# Map function to select object properties based on an array of properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs3, map-function

I would like to find a solution that would allow me to use the map function to extract properties based on an array of properties. Ideally I would like a general solution so that I do not have to hard code the map function for each variation.

My use case: I am building an admin dashboard that will need to display 20+ tables - each with a different combination of columns. Using VueJS I have a table component to render the table but currently each table has the exact same columns being shown.

```
// every table shows these 4 columns
this.rows = this.menu.MenuItem.map(r => ({
   Id: r.Id,
   Name: r.Name,
   Description: r.Description,
   Category: r.Category
}))
```

Instead of the same columns for each table, I would like each table to be able to define which columns it would like to display. The same table component is used for each table, so I need a general solution to avoid writing a massive if-else block.

```
const MenuColumnMapping = [
    { menu: "Menu 1", columns: ["Id", "Name", "Description"] },
    { menu: "Menu 2", columns: ["Id", "Name", "Description", "Category" ] },
    { menu: "Menu 3", columns: ["Id", "Name", "Description", "Price", "Condition" ] },
    ...
]
```

How could I rewrite the `map` function to select the properties based on the array of `columns` for a given menu?

```
let cols = MenuColumnMapping
              .filter((m) => m.menu === this.menu.Name)
              .map((m) => m.columns)

// ex. cols = [ "Id", "Name", "Description", "Category" ]
this.rows = this.menu.MenuItem.map(r => ({
   
   // How can I select only the properties listed in cols

}))
```

Comment: Please see if this helps: `this.menu.MenuItem.map(r => ({ ...cols.reduce((f, k) => { f[k] = r[k]; return f; }, {})}));`

Comment: Not sure if I got your question. Please try this 

`this.menu.MenuItem.filter(r => cols.includes(r)).map(r => 
{
    let obj = {};
    obj[r] = r;
    return obj;
})`